# readonly mutable fields in Swift

Tags: swift, oop

When defining a class in Swift, you can have `var` properties which are like normal fields in other OOP languages, but also `let` properties which are both read-only and immutable (like `T const * const` in C++).

However is there a Swift equivalent of C++'s `T * const`? (That is, the field itself is immutable, but the object it points to is mutable)?

Here's a representation of my scenario:

```
class Foo {
    let bar: Bar
    init(bar: Bar) {
        self.bar = bar
    }
}

protocol Bar {
    var fleem: Int? { get set }
}

class ConcreteBar : Bar {
    var fleem: Int? = nil
}

var foo: Foo = Foo( bar: ConcreteBar() )
foo.bar.fleem = 123
```

(Playground link: https://iswift.org/playground?3jKAiu&v=2 )

Presently this gives me this compiler error:

> ```
> Swift:: Error: cannot assign to property: 'bar' is a 'let' constant`
> foo.bar.fleem = 123
> ```

Note that **I am not actually setting `bar`**, I'm only setting `bar.fleem`. I don't know why the compiler is complaining about assigning to `bar`.

If I change `Foo` to use this:

```
class Foo {
    var bar: Bar
    // ...
```

...then it compiles okay, but then I lose the guarantee that `Foo.bar` always has the same instance.

I know I could also change it to `private(set)`:

```
class Foo {

    public private(set) var bar: Bar
    // ...
```

...but `Foo` itself is still free to overwrite the `bar` object-reference, and the use of `var` means that the compiler cannot assume the reference is immutable either, so some optimizations may be skipped.

I'm looking for something like a hypothetical `let mutable` or `var readonly` keyword or modifier.

Comment: "But the use of let here means that both consumers of SomeData and even itself cannot call anotherNestedObject.someMutatingMethod()." No it doesn't. A `let` class instance is still mutable.

Comment: @matt I've updated my question with a more concrete example.

Comment: Declare `Bar` as a `class` protocol.

Comment: Not interested. Accept Alexander's answer, he took the time for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, protocol typed objects have value value semantics. As a consequence, they're not mutable if the variable is a `let` constant.

To introduce reference semantics (and by extension, the mutability of objects referred to be a `let` constant), you need to make your protocol into a class protocol:

```
protocol Bar: class {
    var fleem: Int? { get set }
}
```

Comment: @Dai Because Arrays are structs. Thus when assigned to `let` constants, they can't be mutated.

Comment: @Dai In no case can you assign a new instance to a `let` constant. But that's not what your question was originally about

Comment: @Dai `let` -> 1) Can't be reassigned new values, 2) can only be mutated if it's a reference type (objects of classes, class protocols). `var` -> 1) Can be reassigned, 2) can be mutated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137619/discussion-between-alexander-and-dai).

Comment: There is no `baz` in your question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `class` attribute to the protocol to make it reference type compliant:

```
protocol Bar : class { ...
```